# Why Even-Odd method for $\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \ln(\sin(x))$ dx doesn't work

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

For $ \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \ln(\sin(x)) $ dx, I tried using the Even-Odd method

Even part = $\frac{\ln(\sin(x)) + \ln(\sin(- x))}{2}$ = $\frac{\ln(\sin(x)) + \ln(-1) + \ln(\sin(x))}{2}$ = $\frac{\ln(-1)}{2} + \ln(\sin(x))$

The integral of the even part would be equal to that of the original function

$$\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \ln(\sin(x)) dx = \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \ln(\sin(x))  + \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{2}\ln(-1) dx $$

$$\rightarrow$$
$$0 = \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{2}\ln(-1) dx $$

Which is not true.

So when using the Even-Odd method, would you count complex values of the function as being equal to 0? Or is there another explanation?

Thanks

Comment: $\ln$ isn't defined for nonpositive real values

Comment: And under any sensible definition of $\log(\cdot)$ on complex numbers, you shouldn't expect $\log(\cdot)$ to satisfy the identity $\log(xy) = \log x+\log y$. Indeed, the best thing you can expect is that this identity holds up to an integer multiple of $2\pi i$: $$ \log(xy) = \log x + \log y \pmod{2\pi i} $$ (This is because $\exp(\cdot)$ is an $2\pi i$-periodic function.)

Comment: In light of the existing comments if $I:=\int_0^{\pi/3}\ln\sin xdx$ then, e.g. on the definition $\ln(-y):=\ln y+i\pi$ for $y>0$,$$\int_{-\pi/3}^0\ln\sin xdx=\frac{i\pi^2}{3}+\int_{-\pi/3}^0\ln\sin|x|dx=\frac{i\pi^2}{3}+I,$$so your original integral is $\frac{i\pi^2}{3}+2I$.